# SQL - How to include NULL values when using MAX() function?

Tags: sql-server, null, max, aggregate-functions, where-clause

I am trying to create a report where it only shows the newest `CoverageGroup`, including null values.

[Sample - Current VS Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmPP1.jpg)

Here is the current code (without MAX() function):

```
SELECT
    p.AcctNumber,
    c.sDate,
    ISNULL(cv.Coveragegroup,0) AS [CoverageGroup],
    wd.Code,
    ISNULL(CO2.lname,'Patient') AS [PrimIns],
    p.DefaultCoverageGroup,
    ISNULL(cv.LevelOfCoverage,0) AS [LevelOfCoverage]
FROM 
    Patient p
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    Charge c ON c.PatientID = p.IDPatient
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    Coverage cv ON cv.PatientiD = p.IDPatient
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    WorkDescriptor wd ON wd.IDWorkdescriptor = c.WorkDescriptorID
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    InsCompany ic on ic.IDInsCompany = cv.InsCompanyID
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    Contact co2 on co2.IDContact = ic.ContactID
WHERE 
    p.AcctNumber IN (256500, 256569)
    AND (cv.Coveragegroup = p.DefaultCoverageGroup OR p.DefaultCoverageGroup = 0)
    AND (cv.LevelOfCoverage = 1 OR cv.LevelOfCoverage IS NULL)
ORDER BY 
    p.AcctNumber, c.sDate
```

I've tried different variations of `MAX(COALESCE...` and `MAX(CASE WHEN...` but they didn't work or they would not show accounts with a null `CoverageGroup`.

Any idea how I could do this? My expertise in SQL is beginner.

Thank you!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I believe it is sql-server.

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe because of this:

```
AND (cv.Coveragegroup = p.DefaultCoverageGroup OR p.DefaultCoverageGroup = 0)
```

Here you actually specify that it is not allowed to be `NULL`.

You can maybe avoid it by changing it to something like this:

```
AND (cv.Coveragegroup = p.DefaultCoverageGroup OR p.DefaultCoverageGroup = 0 OR cv.Coveragegroup IS NULL)
```

Comment: The code I posted does show the null values, however, when I add another line like MAX(COALESCE... or MAX(CASE WHEN... (in attempt to show only the newest CoverageGroup), only then does it not show the accounts with a null CoverageGroup.

Comment: Okay. Remember when you do an aggregate it usually eliminates NULL values. You can probably get your desired result by doing one `SELECT` statement where you do you  `MAX()` and then `UNION ALL` with a statement where you only show the rows with `NULL` values.

Comment: I haven't done UNION ALL before, but I can try it. Thank you.

Comment: It is pretty simple.. `SELECT * FROM Table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Table2`. Only catch is the tables must be of equal size with respect to columns (and data types).